# Environment configurations for Overflow checking c#?

Tags: c#

Overflow checking can be enabled by compiler options, environment configuration, or use of the checked keyword. So what are the environment Configurations for this ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked

Comment: If that's a quote, it may help to know where it's from.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked

Comment: Bearing in mind that the C# language is specific to run on any compliant host, it may be talking about a possibility that isn't currently surfaced in any current MS execution environment implementations. At least, I can't find anything listed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/clr-configuration-knobs.md).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I guess it could just be a syntax thing? some people may view "checking a box in the IDE properties window" or "specifying something in xml in the csproj" as being different to "compiler options"

Comment: The author of the article is a bit confused.  The only environment variable that plays a role in C# compilation is LIB, it can set the directory for reference assemblies.  You do have to use the -check command line option to control it.